# Inserting/pasting text into active window?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'd like to insert/paste a text in the currently active window and at the focussed element within there, which most likely won't be the app itself (but could be).

I already checked (close to) all clipboard packages / capabilities and it doesn't appear it is possible to initiate a paste event from there. Other solutions for inserting text only seem to be for within the app / mostly for inserting into files.

Tried creating a keyboard even in the rendered process with JS, but this would be limited to the renderer, and I think it should be in the main to even access anything outside the renderer.

Anyone know how to do this / confirm whether or not its even possible?

Comment: You can use electron's [clipboard](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/clipboard.md) to actually manage the text. Then you can pass it to your element using ipc channels or `executeJavascript` I suppose.

Comment: @pergy using ipc I can send it to my rendered process, but I want it to be inserted in any app/window that is currently active, which is most likely not the app itself. Don't believe this is possible with ipc, or did I miss functionality there?

Comment: I see, I missed that point. ipc channels are useless there indeed.

Answer (score 5):

You could do this using a combination of electron's [clipboard](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/clipboard) module to get the contents of the clipboard and [robotjs](http://robotjs.io/docs/examples) `typeString` method to type the string into other applications:

```
const { clipboard } = require('electron');
const robot = require('robotjs');
const text = clipboard.readText();
robot.typeString(text);
```

Answer (score 2):

If the text is already in your clipboard, why not just use the paste keyboard command (Ctrl+V)?

```
robot.keyTap('v', ['control']);
```